# Casting operator :: not being parsed by Apache Calcite

Tags: sql, postgresql, parsing, apache-calcite

I'm encountering a particular issue with a simple Apache Calcite planner I've set up using the following code:

```java
SqlParser.Config parserConfig = SqlParser.configBuilder()
                .setCaseSensitive(false)
                .setUnquotedCasing(Casing.UNCHANGED)
                .setQuotedCasing(Casing.UNCHANGED)
                .setConformance(SqlConformanceEnum.BABEL)
                .build();

FrameworkConfig frameworkConfig = Frameworks.newConfigBuilder()
                .parserConfig(parserConfig)
                .operatorTable(SqlLibraryOperatorTableFactory.INSTANCE.getOperatorTable(
                        SqlLibrary.POSTGRESQL))
                .sqlValidatorConfig(SqlValidator.Config.DEFAULT.withIdentifierExpansion(true))
                .defaultSchema(connection.getRootSchema().getSubSchema(defaultSchema))
                .build();

Planner planner = Frameworks.getPlanner(frameworkConfig);
```

Now, I'm trying to parse the following query using the planner I created (`SqlNode parsedQuery = planner.parse(sql);`):

```sql
SELECT lineitem.l_shipdate :: text AS l_shipdate
FROM lineitem
```

The query executes without any problems in PostgreSQL. However, when attempting to parse it with Calcite, I encounter the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException: Encountered ":" at line 1, column 28.
Was expecting one of:
    "UESCAPE" ...
    <QUOTED_STRING> ...
    ")" ...
    "," ...
    "." ...
    "NOT" ...
    "IN" ...
    "<" ...
    "<=" ...
    ">" ...
    ">=" ...
    "=" ...
    "<>" ...
    "!=" ...
    "BETWEEN" ...
    "LIKE" ...
    "ILIKE" ...
    "RLIKE" ...
    "SIMILAR" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "%" ...
    "||" ...
    "AND" ...
    "OR" ...
    "IS" ...
    "MEMBER" ...
    "SUBMULTISET" ...
    "CONTAINS" ...
    "OVERLAPS" ...
    "EQUALS" ...
    "PRECEDES" ...
    "SUCCEEDS" ...
    "IMMEDIATELY" ...
    "MULTISET" ...
    "[" ...
    "FORMAT" ...
    
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.convertException(SqlParserImpl.java:408)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.impl.SqlParserImpl.normalizeException(SqlParserImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.handleException(SqlParser.java:159)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseQuery(SqlParser.java:174)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseStmt(SqlParser.java:199)
    at org.apache.calcite.prepare.PlannerImpl.parse(PlannerImpl.java:216)
    at org.apache.calcite.tools.Planner.parse(Planner.java:50)
    at de.tub.dima.mascara.parser.Parser.getLogicalPlan(Parser.java:67)
    at de.tub.dima.mascara.Playground.main(Playground.java:34)
```

I've tried setting the conformance of the parser to multiple values, such as `SqlConformanceEnum.BABEL`, `SqlConformanceEnum.BIG_QUERY`, etc., but still without success. This issue is perplexing because this type of operator should be supported (as indicated in the [documentation](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html)).

I appreciate any assistance you can provide. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I removed the information about the UDF I created because is irrelevant to the problem of parsing the cast operator ::

Comment: Why have the spaces around the double colon? try `SELECT generalize_date(lineitem.l_shipdate, 'MONTH'::text)` **but** 'MONTH' is a string, do you really need an explicit type conversion? **OR** try without the double colon `SELECT generalize_date(lineitem.l_shipdate, CAST('MONTH' AS text))`

Comment: Hi Paul, that was a valid idea but I tried removing the blank spaces, and the result is the same: Postgres executes the query and Calcite fails when parsing the casting operator. Also calling only using 'MONTH' without the cast works on Postgres. However, on Calcite it tries to search for an identifier MONTH even if it is quoted and supposed to be parsed as a string. `generalize_date(lineitem.l_shipdate, CAST('MONTH' AS text))` also doesn't work throwing a `CalciteContextException: Unknown identifier 'text'`

Comment: Hmmmm. I have no further ideas - sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I managed a workaround to avoid the casting operator. Still, I'm curious why Calcite is unable to parse the casting operator. I could understand if it were a validation error but setting the conformance to BABEL should definitely parse properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Calcite has three built-in parser implementations:

- SqlParserImpl (Default, parser for SQL statements closely following the SQL Standard)
- SqlDdlParserImpl (parser for DDL statements; these are not standardised so they are not in the default parser)
- SqlBabelParserImpl (parser for SQL statements with more exotic syntax that is not part of SQL standard)

The parser implementation can be chosen by calling one of the methods below:

- [Config#withParserFactory](https://calcite.apache.org/javadocAggregate/org/apache/calcite/sql/parser/SqlParser.Config.html#withParserFactory(org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParserImplFactory))
- [ConfigBuilder#setParserFactory](https://calcite.apache.org/javadocAggregate/org/apache/calcite/sql/parser/SqlParser.ConfigBuilder.html#setParserFactory(org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParserImplFactory))(Deprecated)

In this case you are using the Postgres cast operator '::' which was introduced in the Babel parser in [CALCITE-2843](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-2843) so in this case you have to pass `SqlBabelParserImpl.FACTORY` to one of the methods above.

SqlConformance is a supplementary configuration that can fine tune the behavior of the parser & validator no matter which parser implementation is used underneath.

Comment: Hi Zabetak. Thank you for your answer. I saw that ISSUE before. However, using SqlBabelParserImpl returns another kind of excection:
`Receiver class org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.babel.SqlBabelParserImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void switchTo(org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlAbstractParserImpl$LexicalState)' of abstract class org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlAbstractParserImpl.`

Comment: Ups my mistake. I used the wrong release for the `calcite-babel` artifact. Now it works! Thank you Zabetak! 
Ps. For anyone else having this exception use the same calcite version for the `calcite-babel` artifact as you use for the `calcite-core` artifact